# is there a special consideration when chosing a 2 phases or 3 phases control softstart

Tags: motor, ac

softstart for 100 kW AC motor will be used, but with wich type of softstart :

- control on 2 phases
- control on all three phases

Comment: Would a VFD be too much?

Comment: no need for VFD,

Answer (score 1):

The only possible advantage of a 2-phase softstart is a lower price.

Assuming that there is no electromechanical bypass contactor, the forward voltage drop of the SCR's introduces a slight voltage imbalance. That causes a  current imbalance that is larger than the voltage imbalance, but still small. However, there will be some increased heating in the motor.

If one SCR shorts, the motor will continue to receive single-phase power until the a circuit breaker, fuse or disconnect switch opens. With SCRs in all three phases, that would only happen if two SCRs in two phases are shorted.

There is also this from an Eaton Corp. publication:

> The asymmetrical trigger control developed and patented
>   ... by Moeller, an Eaton brand ... avoids DC components, which normally result on a two-phase–controlled soft start controller. Asymmetrical trigger control suppresses the formation of an elliptical rotating field, which leads to uneven stresses in the motor and extended acceleration times. ... this asymmetric trigger control is active during the start and stop ramp.

Consider:

1. Is the cost of the 2-phase model a little less than the 3-phase?
2. Is the motor duty less than operating 24-7 right at full-load?
3. Are you concerned about a loss in efficiency that you can probably not measure?
4. Are you concerned about the consequences of the failure of an SCR? In other words, what is the worst that can happen if someone presses the stop button and the machine doesn't stop?
5. Do you have any worry that the motor might not last longer than the rest of the equipment?

There are many situations in which it makes perfect sense to buy the less expensive alternative.

Comment: i see, but if we consider that Siemens produces 2 phases control softstart we have to ask : is it so bad that we should avoid using this type of softstart?

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: if the number of starting is less than 3 by week, the type of softstart shoul not be so important, no?

Comment: All of the disadvantages pertain the the continued presence of the soft start in the circuit. Total time used per week would be important. The number of starts would probably not be very important. Note that a soft start that includes electromechanical bypass would have only the failure mode concern. Electromechanical bypass would eliminate the small efficiency reduction caused by any type of bypass.

Comment: Great answer, dead on. I'll add something pertaining to the Eaton blurb you included, but because it's so long I'll put it in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Re: the claim made by Eaton in the first answer:

Siemens makes the exact same claim (including saying it is "exclusive") but both of them are referring only to mitigating the DC component in the starting power due to the single phase starting. But no matter what they do, the current going to the motor is ALWAYS unbalanced during starting with a 2-phase design. That unbalanced current creates negative sequence currents in the rotor, which in turn creates negative torque. That means the motor is "fighting itself" during acceleration, which translates to having LESS accelerating torque *per-unit of current going to the motor*. So a 2-phase soft starter means you get less effective accelerating torque while using a limited amount of current (if that is the desired effect), or more current for the same amount of accelerating torque. Either way, a full 3-phase (6 SCR) starter is better at accelerating a motor than a 2-phase (4 SCR) design. You should never use a 2-phase design for any heavy or high inertia loads or those that need long acceleration times. Bottom line, they (2-phase) are fine for centrifugal pumps and fans that can accelerate fast and are basically unloaded at first, but probably nothing else.

And like he said, ALWAYS consider the failure mode!

Comment: thanks for the reply, the use is for a centrifugal pump 100 kW and one proposal is the Siemens 3RW40 (2 ph control i think)